# How can I use xml file without listbox in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I want to ask you that I have one xml file that I query data from. However, I don't want to use listbox to assign data from query to it because I use "where statement" which only one record will be received, and I also already have the number of controls coresponding to the number of data in query. Therefore, how can I assign each individual data in query to each individual contorl such as textblock and radio button without a help of listbox?

In short, can we use itemCollection from query statement without listbox?

Comment: You can query your XML with Linq which should give you the data however you need it. I'd then populate an object with that data and  bind the object to whatever control is best for you. A ListBox is great because you are very free to define the layout of each item in the DataTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your controls to `StackPanel` or `Grid` and access them in a loop with `Children` property.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you give me code example in xaml and cs files? how can we access specific individual data from query? Say like, textblock name = query["index_of_name"]; textblock id = query['index_of_id']?

Comment: I don't know how your data is structured. Your query returns IEnumerable<[Custom Class]> right? I'd use .List() on query and then you can then access individual items by index. List[i].YourProperty.

Comment: since character limited, let me explain it, my application is like a quiz that have one text block for the question, and 3 or 4 radio buttons for answer. therefore, in my question.xaml file contains 1 textblock which its text attribute bound to question, and 3 or 4 radio buttons which its content attribute bound to answerA to answerD, and 1 next button, all is not within the listbox. My question.xml file has <questions> as the root element, and <question> as child elements which have attributes of questionId, question, and answerA to answerD and class test.cs that has all xml attributes.

Comment: I am really experienced with XML, but if you create node names same then you could read it easily. I think this question could be your answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118788/linq-to-xml-how-to-select-the-next-element